# Blender not able to use gpu

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

When I try to render my scene in Blender, it will only render on gpu, not cpu.
I went to the preference tab to see what settings I could change to make it work, but I was greeted to this:[image: It doesnt recognise my gpu as compatible in any of the tabs]

I've tried updating to the most recent version of Blender and GPU drivers.
Specs:
RX 580
16 GB ram
Ryzen 5 2600

Comment: What happens if you switch to CUDA? - My own RTX 2070 gives the same error message if I click 'HIP' so you'd need a much higher spec graphics card to use HIP.

Comment: @JohnEason I have indeed tried switching to all of the render devices and none of them get found. Also I thought CUDA was Nvidia? I'm using an amd gpu.

Comment: Sorry. You're correct about CUDA and Optix being Nvidia only, however your gpu doesn't seem to be capable of using HIP according to [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#hip-amd) in the Blender manual. Best to check on [AMD's web site](https://www.amd.com/en/graphics) to see if your gpu is supported.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed so. I figured that my gpu just wasnt good enough but I was hoping that there was some way to make it work. Thanks for the answers though!